# How can we create modal pop-up in angular from scratch

Tags: html, css, angular

Need to create a modal popup on button click, 
is there any way to make it from scratch without adding any extra dependency for it,
with the below method, I am getting the fully functional modal, but have no confidence whether this is a good way in angular or not,
please suggest

HTML

```
<button class="hl-sort" (click)="openSortingModal()">
Sort
</button>
<div class="modal-container" *ngIf="modalContent">
  <h1>i am modal content</h1>
  <button (click)="closeModal()">Close</button>
</div>
```

components.ts

```
modalContent = false;
openSortingModal(){
  this.modalContent = true;
  console.log('clicked')
}
closeModal(){
 this.modalContent = false;
}
```

Comment: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/04/16/angular-7-custom-modal-window-dialog-box this might be helpful for you

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to add any extra dependency, I suggest you create a re-usable component using HTML + CSS as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  template: `
    <div #myModal class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Some content here...</p>
      <button (click)="close()">Close</button>
    </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent {

  @ViewChild('myModal', {static: false}) modal: ElementRef;

  open() {
    this.modal.nativeElement.style.display = 'block';
  }

  close() {
    this.modal.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Then use it in your container:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal/modal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <app-modal #modal></app-modal>
    <p>
    Open a Pure HTML + CSS with Angular
    </p>
    <button (click)="openModal()">Open Modal</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: []
})
export class AppComponent  {

  @ViewChild('modal', {static: false}) modal: ModalComponent

  openModal() {
    this.modal.open();
  }
}
```

See a working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-html-css

I hope it helps!

Comment: I have taken the liberty of improving your answer to allow close the modal if you click outside

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to reinvent the wheel, you can use this

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Answer (score 1):

well, if you want to "re-invent the wheel", don't forget close the modal when you click outside

improving the Luixaviles's answer, the component modal can be like

```
<div #myModal class="container" (click)="tryClose()">
  <div #content class="content">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

Well, you see that I make a function "tryClose" if you click on the div "myModal", this function check if we click but we don't click inside "content"

```
  tryClose() {
    const clickTarget = event.target as HTMLElement;
    if (!(this.content.nativeElement as HTMLElement).contains(clickTarget))
      this.close();
  }
```

Using `<ng-content>` allow us write in app.component some like

```
<app-modal #modal>
    <p>Some content here...</p>
    <button (click)="modal.close()">Close</button>
</app-modal>
<p>
   Open a Pure HTML + CSS with Angular
</p>
<button (click)="modal.open()">Open Modal</button>
```

The rest of code in modal component is simple:

```
export class ModalComponent {
  @ViewChild("myModal", { static: false }) modal: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("content", { static: false }) content: ElementRef;

  open() {
    this.modal.nativeElement.style.display = "block";
  }

  close() {
    this.modal.nativeElement.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

See the [Luixaviles's forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-html-css-wfxyfm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal%2Fmodal.component.ts)

**Update** a simple stopPropagation makes the thinks easer

```
   <div #myModal class="container" (click)="close()">
      <div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" class="content">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it is a good idea to create your own component rather using a third party. Just make sure, your popup must be a reusable or dynamic popup.